# How to Enable/Disable mouse scroll with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to enable/disable scrolling with javascript,

I managed to disable the scrolling however fail to put it back to working state,

so what I've tried is:

```
 function noscroll() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

and I try to add and remove scrolling with the following lines of code

```
 window.removeEventListener("scroll", noscroll);

 window.addEventListener("scroll", noscroll);
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can't you just hide the scrollbar instead?

Comment: this is usually solved with CSS, `overflow:none` - a js based approach like this might cause jittery scrolling effects

Comment: thx I'll try both approaches! and let you know

Comment: You still haven't explained what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach appears to work as shown here:

```js
function noscroll() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", noscroll);
});
 
document.getElementById('disable').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", noscroll);  
});
```

```css
div {
  background:pink;
  height:1000px;
  padding:50px;
}

header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<header>
<button id="enable">Enable scrolling</button>
<button id="disable">Disable scrolling</button>
</header>
<div>
Prevent scroll via Javascript (window.scrollTo)
</div>
```

Another approach worth considering, is to update the `overflow` property of your `document.body` element by "hiding" any content overflow. This has the side effect of removing the scrollbar, which in turn, prevents scrolling:

```js
 document.getElementById('enable').addEventListener('click', () => {

    // Remove overflow value from document body to restore default scrolling
    document.body.style.overflow = '';
 })

 document.getElementById('disable').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // When scrolling is disabled, auto scroll to top of screen
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    // Apply overflow:hidden to document body to prevent scrolling
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
 })
```

```css
div {
  background:pink;
  height:1000px;
  padding:50px;
}

header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<header>
<button id="enable">Enable scrolling</button>
<button id="disable">Disable scrolling</button>
</header>
<div>
Prevent scroll via CSS
</div>
```

The main advantage of the CSS based approach shown above is that it's not subject to "jittery" scrolling behaviour that can be noticable with the former "pure-javascript" approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach works, so what is your question?

```js
function noScroll() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}

forbid.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', noScroll)
})

allow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', noScroll)
})
```

```css
div { 
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 150vh;
  line-height: 150vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="forbid">Forbid scrolling</button>
<button type="button" id="allow">Allow scrolling</button>
<div>scroll me</div>
```

Comment: well the way I wrote add/remove event listeners does not work, however I tried your code and it works!